# How to write query by using findBy..() methods for one record

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've an entity class User_Details

```
package vl.cybersecurityapplication.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User_Details")
public class User_Details implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "UserId")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "E_Mail")
    private String eMail;
    @Column(name = "Mobile_Num")
    private int mobileNumber;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my repo interface

```
package vl.cybersecurityapplication.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import vl.cybersecurityapplication.model.User_Details;

public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User_Details, Long> {

    public Integer findMobileNumberByName(String userName);


}
```

This is my repo class

```
package vl.cybersecurityapplication.repository;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import vl.cybersecurityapplication.model.User_Roles;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository{

    @Autowired
    IUserRepository userRepository;

    public Integer findMobileNumberByName(@PathVariable String lastName) {
        int mobileNumber = userRepository.findMobileNumberByName("shaik");
        System.out.println("Mobile Number : "+mobileNumber);
        return mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Spring Boot and JPA.
Here I need to query mobile number in User_Details table by using lastname.
i.e., Select Mobile_Num from User_Details where LastName= "xyz";
Can Some one help me how to wo write this query in my repo class.

Comment: please Show us your objects wich are neeeded for the query. JPA is object based

Comment: @Jens Can you please respond now

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a native query. JPA supports object based query.
You can use List findByLastName(String lastname) which will generate that query in the backend and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this. But you cannot fetch only MobileNumber. You will get a complete object.

```
 List<User> findByLastName(String lastname).
```

If you want to get only some fields then you should check out [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts)

Comment: then what is the return type. Please mention return type also